# Generating browser side web page thumbnails

Tags: html, iframe, thumbnails

I want to generate a thumbnail of a web page in the browser, so I can have multiple scaled down iFrames within a single page.

IE can do this using filters. Mozilla can do this inside a <canvas> with drawWindow() if you have Chrome privileges (like an installed plug-in).

Is there any way to do this in WebKit? Is there any generic cross browser way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I know you're looking for a client-side way to do this, but considering the spotty support across the board you may want to look into generating the thumbnails on the server.

[khtml2png](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/) allows you to generate webpage images from the command line. It's not the prettiest solution, but with a little scripting it would allow you to generate thumbnails on the fly, and you wouldn't have to worry about browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

WebKit's nightly build (41944 from March 24 2009) has support for transforming elements (including scaling) as well as other goodies like CSS gradients.

There is more information on the WebKit blog and [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/04/25/css-gradients-transforms-animations-and-masks/).

I'm guessing this features are also available in Safari 4 but I haven't checked.

edit: It looks like this is also making its way into Mozilla as [-moz-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-transform).